# As an EU national just moved to France, how do I get a "Attestation d'accueil" for a friend's visa?

Tags: france, visa, schengen

I'd previously said to an Indian friend that they ought to come over and stay with me in the summer. At the time, I'd thought I'd be in the UK, and I'm fairly happy about how to go about helping them get a UK visa. Now it looks like I'll have just moved to France, so they'll need to get a Schengen visa instead.

Looking at the [France Diplomatie site on this](http://www.diplomatie.gouv.fr/fr/venir-en-france-22365/formalites-d-entree-en-france/article/controle-a-l-arrivee-en-france) ([English version](http://www.diplomatie.gouv.fr/en/coming-to-france/getting-a-visa/article/verification-upon-arrival-in)), I gather I'll need to get something called a "Attestation d' Accueil" for my friend confirming that they'll be staying with me.

From an earlier question, I gather [“carte de séjour” is not required for EU citizens](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/180/as-an-eu-national-moving-to-france-what-are-the-rules-about-registering). So, I won't have one of those. As an EU national recently moved to France, I probably won't have a great deal in the way of French paperwork.

In that situation, how would I go about getting a "Attestation d' Accueil"? Especially what will I need to get for myself first, and how would I do that? Related, will the process for applying for one once I have the right documentation be the same as for a local, or will it differ as an EU national?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to obtain this “*attestation d'accueil*” from the municipal authorities (“*à la mairie*”) where you live. It's supposed to prove that you have enough space and financial means to accommodate the person (and will consequently reduce the financial means requirement for the Schengen visa).

You will need to fill in a form (you can [download a sample form](http://vosdroits.service-public.fr/particuliers/R10751.xhtml) to know how it looks like but you will get the actual form from the *mairie* as well). You will also have to provide several documents and pay a fee.

Here is a list (translated from [service-public.fr](http://vosdroits.service-public.fr/particuliers/F2191.xhtml)):

- An ID
- Something proving you can use the house/flat where your guest will be staying (i.e. a contract if you are renting, etc.)
- A proof of address (recent utility bill)
- Anything that shows you have sufficient financial means (tax returns – but you won't have that if you just moved – and salary slips are mentioned)
- Anything that shows the place you are staying is suitable (i.e. how big it is, etc.)
- A 30 € *timbre fiscal* to pay the application fee (you can buy one in a “*bureau de tabac*”)

You need to show originals of all these documents and, depending on the place, they will make copies for you or you have to provide them as well (the site advises you to ask beforehand). You also need to know the passport number of your guest and decide who will pay for the mandatory health insurance (i.e. you or your visiting friend).