# Attestation d'accueil - what in the world is "etat sanitaire" and how do I prove it?

Tags: visa, france

I am an Indian citizen on an EU D/Scientific visa in France. My local mayor's office ([mairie](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mairie)) is [Gif-sur-yvette](http://www.ville-gif.fr/).

The Mairie has [certain documents](http://www.ville-gif.fr/mairie/formalites-administratives/attestation-daccueil/) that need to be produced for a attestation d'accueil for my parents' visit in Jan/Feb 2015 from India. This list has been discussed elsewhere on [expats.SE](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/a/346/133).

However, an additional document that is required by my Mairie is "**etat sanitaire**" (state of sanitation) [(see 1 pg pdf document)](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13223318/ATTESTATION%20D'ACCUEIL.pdf). How do I prove that?

I live in a rented apartment and I and my landlord are both looking for how to prove "etat sanitaire".

Comment: You may want to edit your question and include appropriate information rather than including a link. This may be frown upon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this instance, *état sanitaire* refers to the conditions of the place where you will be staying at. Is it safe, clean, free of pests, does it meet the minimum safety, health, standard, etc.

I am guessing that the French administration wants to avoid individuals staying in unsanitary conditions while in their country.

You may want to bring photos of the place where you are staying but I am guessing that *renseignements* refers to the verbal information you need to provide, not justifications.

Comment: Yes, I brought photos of my apartment with me to the Mayor's office. They didn't quite care about the photos and said they were not sure how to judge the *etat sanitaire*. I got my attestation d'accueil anyway.